# Mid Game Mob Farm Designs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need a mob farm to get bonemeal very quickly, so I need a mob farm but getting 30 stacks of cobble is hard, especially since strip mining leads to some cave somewhere…

I need a Monday farm design the needs like 1-10 cobblestone and it's actually reasonable to get mid game.

I’m trying to get dark oak in my single player world to get tons of emeralds to get goods.
To get dark oak quick I need bonemeal (same to get crops).
How can I do this? I don’t have a cobblestone generator as I don’t have enough lava.

I can get diamond tools from villagers if I have enough emerals, so I need this.
Please help me.

Comment: Ever heard of a cobblestone/stone generator? Hook it up with a few pistons and you've got a reasonable amount of cobble

Comment: If 30 stacks of cobble is hard for you, and you don't have enough lava for a cobblestone generator, you aren't mid-game yet. Not by a long shot.